# Apache unacceptably slow

Tags: apache-2.2

Getting pages on my apache is currently unacceptably slow, even locally. I have no clue what may be going on, but the processors seem pretty inactive, and there are 7GB of free memory. Any ideas? Take a look at this time/curl test:

```
muiraquitã 3:49 ~ % time curl 127.0.0.1
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /index.html
on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.9 (Debian) PHP/5.2.6-1+lenny3 with Suhosin-Patch Server at 127.0.0.1 Port 80</address>
</body></html>
**curl 127.0.0.1  0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 17.768 total**
```

Comment: Anything special about your config?  Custom authentication modules, proxy rules, etc?  Where are the files?  Local, or remote like NFS or on a SAN?  What is the system?  Virtual, or bare metal?

Comment: Any update on this?  Did you find a resolution?

Answer (score 3):

That kinda smells like DNS lookup timeouts.  Try turning off HostnameLookups and see whether that improves the situation.

Comment: Hmm, it was already off on apache2.conf :(

Answer (score 0):

If you disable access restriction to index.html do you get better results ? Do you use NIS or serve / from a remote filesystem or some raid rebuild is in progress ? index.html is static or dynamic generated content ?